# Ripping audio CD from Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, ripping

How can I rip an audio CD from the command line in Windows?

I've noticed that there are many programs under Linux, but under Windows, all CD rippers are with a graphical interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's actually quite a few options

I'm personally a huge fan of [cuetools](http://www.cuetools.net/wiki/Main_Page), and one of the options it has is the cuetools console ripper - download the cuetools archive, unrar and just run `CUETools.ConsoleRipper.exe`. The command `CUETools.ConsoleRipper.exe --help` gives the options

```
Usage    : CUERipper.exe <options>

-S, --secure             secure mode, read each block twice (default);
-B, --burst              burst (1 pass) mode;
-P, --paranoid           maximum level of error correction;
-D, --drive <letter>     use a specific CD drive, e.g. D: ;
-O, --offset <samples>   use specific drive read offset;
-T, --test               detect read command;
--d8                     force D8h read command;
--be                     force BEh read command;
```

And it tags using musicbrainz, so its automatic and probably correct.

Another option I see mentioned is CDDA2Wav from cdrtools - [this seems to be the place](http://www.student.tugraz.at/thomas.plank/) to get windows binaries for it. Not tested by me.

You might also be able to run your favourite linux cli ripper in cygwin.