# How do I rip an audio CD using VLC?

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player

I've been trying to use VLC to rip a CD, using the `Convert / Save` menu option as shown in [this guide](https://www.wondershare.com/vlc/rip-audio-cd-with-vlc.html). Whenever I try this, though, no matter what settings I pick, I get a 0 byte file. What's the correct way to rip a CD to file?

Comment: Here is the answer that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607084/1310267

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. It turned out that in the first menu 'start position' was set to track "0". Simply changing it to 1 or whatever track you want to rip should solve it

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting your preferences, by going to `Tools->Preferences` and clicking on `Reset Preferences`. Apparently [changing the bitrate even once garbles the output](https://www.vlchelp.com/convert-audio-format/#comment-71).

You might also try [this batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607084/40352).

There are many other ripping tools recommended on Superuser, as well (see [here for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/187275/how-do-i-rip-an-audio-cd-to-a-single-file), and [here for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/488832/ripping-audio-cd-from-windows-command-line)).

Comment: Chris, you soliloquized? You say to yourself, "Try resetting your preferences"? :))

Comment: Just following house style :P

Comment: Aaand in the end the conversion stuttered, so I ended up using WMP to rip and VLC to convert the ripped file.

Comment: Since you are moving beyond VLC -- check http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/